# State-Value initialization

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

can someone explain the effect of different initialization to state-value function, and specifically to the terminal state? in the book "Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction" it was mentioned to initialize the terminal state-value to zero but without an explanation.
Does someone have exmaples where doing so will matter and an examples where it won't?